# React Native App Crashes on Startup with TypeError related to a property shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection being undefined (CometChat Related?)

Tags: android, react-native, sockets, release, cometchat

I am developing a React Native app that I am deploying for Android and recently encountered a crash on startup. The log indicates a TypeError related to a property shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection being undefined.

The app without Hermes as the JavaScript engine. Here are the relevant parts of the log:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.CometChat.appSettings.shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection'), stack: <unknown>@3551:333610 ...
```

The app with Hermes as the JavaScript engine. Here are the relevant parts of the log:

```
2024-03-06 07:25:25.129  7771-7809  ReactNativeJS           com.podium                           E  TypeError: Cannot read property 'shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

...
The crash seems to occur immediately upon startup, and it's unclear why shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection is undefined since it's part of the initial configuration for CometChat, which we're using for messaging in the app. Here is a full log:

```
TypeError: undefined                                                                                       is not an object
                                                                                                    (evaluating                                                                                                  'i.CometChat.appSettings.shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection')
2024-03-06 09:05:19.664  8787-8829  AndroidRuntime          com.podium                           E  FATAL
                                                                                                    EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
                                                                                                    Process: com.podium, PID: 8787
                                                                                                    com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined                                                                                                  is not an object                                                                                                   (evaluating                                                                                                   'i.CometChat.appSettings.shouldAutoEstablishSocketConnection'), stack:                                                                                                   <unknown>@3551:333610                                                                                                   <unknown>@455:891                                                                                                   value@23:787                                                                                                    value@10:847                                                                                                   value@39:3897                                                                                                    <unknown>@39:693                                                                                                    value@39:2528                                                                                                    value@39:664                                                                                                    value@-1                                                                                                                                                                                                    at                                                                                                   com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)                                                                                                       at                                                                                              java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native                                                                                             Method)                                                                                                      at                                                                                                  com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)                                                                                                  at                                                                                                   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:149)                                                                                                     at                                                                                                   com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native                                                                                                  Method)                                                                                                    at                                                                                                    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)                                                                                                   at                                                                                                   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                                        at                                                                                                  com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)                                                                                                    at                                                                                                  android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)                                                                                                     at                                                                                                  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)                                                                                                     at                                                                                                    com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:234)                                                                                                     at                                                                                                 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

this is my app.js code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {CometChat} from '@cometchat/chat-sdk-react-native';
import {CometChatCalls} from '@cometchat/calls-sdk-react-native';
import { initParticle } from './particle'; 
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import Login from './components/login/Login';
import SignUp from './components/register/SignUp';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Search from './components/search/Search';
import CreateRoom from './components/room/CreateRoom';
import EditRoom from './components/room/EditRoom';
import RoomDetail from './components/room/RoomDetail';
import Call from './components/call/Call';
import Notifications from './components/notifications/Notifications';

import {cometChatConfig} from './env';

import {showMessage, showMessageWithActions} from './services/ui';

import Context from './context';

import Compass from './images/compass.svg';
import Logout from './images/logout.svg';
import Bell from './images/bell.svg';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [roomDetail, setRoomDetail] = useState(null);
  // In your context file or app-level state management
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);

  const initCometChat = async () => {
   
    const appID = cometChatConfig.cometChatAppId;
    const region = cometChatConfig.cometChatRegion;
    console.log("This is the appID cometChat is configured to use: ", appID);
    console.log("This is the region cometChat is configured to use: ", region);
  
    try {
      // Initialize CometChat
      const appSetting = new CometChat.AppSettingsBuilder()
        .subscribePresenceForAllUsers()
        .setRegion(region)
        .autoEstablishSocketConnection(true)
        .build();
      await CometChat.init(appID, appSetting);
      console.log("Initialization completed successfully");
    
      //CometCall (audio & video) sign in
      // Initialize CometChatCalls
      const callAppSettings = new CometChatCalls.CallAppSettingsBuilder()
        .setAppId(appID)
        .setRegion(region)
        .build();
      await CometChatCalls.init(callAppSettings);
      console.log('CometChatCalls was initialized successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Initialization failed with error:", error);
    }
  };

  const initAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
    console.log("Initiate Authenticated User...");
    const authenticatedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth');
    setUser(() => (authenticatedUser ? JSON.parse(authenticatedUser) : null));
    console.log("User is set");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async () => {
    try {
      await initCometChat();
      console.log("init cometChat done");
      initParticle();
      console.log("init Particle done");
      await initAuthenticatedUser();
      console.log("init authenticated user done");
      
      setIsInitialized(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during initialization:", error);
      // Handle the error, e.g., setting an error message state to display to the user
      showMessage('Error', 'Initialization error: ' + error.message);
    }
  };
  
    initialize();
  }, []);

  const search = (navigation) => () => {
    navigation.navigate('Search');
  };

  const notifications = (navigation) => () => {
    navigation.navigate('Notifications');
  };

  const logout = (navigation) => () => {
    showMessageWithActions({
      title: 'Confirm',
      message: 'Do you want to log out?',
      actions: [
        {text: 'Cancel'},
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => handleLogout(navigation)},
      ],
    });
  };

  const handleLogout = async (navigation) => {
    await CometChat.logout();
    removeAuthedInfo();
    navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{name: 'Login'}],
    });
  };

  const removeAuthedInfo = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth');
    setUser(null);
  };

  const leaveRoom = (navigation) => async () => {
    try {
      await leaveCometChatGroup();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  const leaveCometChatGroup = async () => {
    if (roomDetail && roomDetail.createdBy.email !== user.email) {
      await CometChat.leaveGroup(roomDetail.id);
    } else {
      showMessage('Info', 'Owner cannot leave the room');
    }
  };

  if (user) {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{user, setUser, roomDetail, setRoomDetail}}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={Home}
              options={({navigation}) => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
                headerLeft: () => (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={search(navigation)}>
                    <Compass width={36} height={36} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
                headerRight: () => (
                  <View style={styles.homeHeaderRight}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={notifications(navigation)}
                      style={styles.bellBtn}>
                      <Bell width={24} height={24} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={logout(navigation)}>
                      <Logout width={24} height={24} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ),
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Search"
              component={Search}
              options={() => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Create Room"
              component={CreateRoom}
              options={() => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Edit Room"
              component={EditRoom}
              options={() => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Room Detail"
              component={RoomDetail}
              options={({navigation}) => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
                headerRight: () => (
                  <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={leaveRoom(navigation)}>
                      <Text style={styles.leaveQuitelyTxt}>Leave Quitely</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ),
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Call" component={Call} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Notifications"
              component={Notifications}
              options={() => ({
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F1EFE3',
                },
              })}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homeHeaderRight: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  bellBtn: {
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  leaveQuitelyTxt: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;
```

These are my packages and dependencies:

```
"@cometchat/calls-sdk-react-native": "^4.0.4",
    "@cometchat/chat-sdk-react-native": "^4.0.5",
    "@cometchat/chat-uikit-react-native": "^4.2.2",
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.7.0",
    "@particle-network/rn-auth": "^1.3.10",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.22.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^12.3.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.3.0",
    "@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-native/metro-babel-transformer": "^0.73.15",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.20",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "emoji-mart-native": "^0.6.5-beta",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "ethers": "^6.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.8.0",
    "idb": "8.0.0",
    "metro-config": "^0.80.6",
    "metro-runtime": "^0.80.6",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.5",
    "react-native-autolink": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-callstats": "3.73.22",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.0.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-webrtc": "118.0.1",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "validator": "^13.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Here's what I've tried so far without success:

Checking all dependencies are up to date.
Cleaning the build folder and reinstalling node modules.
Verifying CometChat is correctly initialized with the provided appID and region. Tested it in debug mode where it works.
Restructuring the initializations to wait in sequence.
I suspect the issue might be related to how CometChat is initialized or possibly a conflict with another package, but I'm not sure how to diagnose or fix it, especially since the issue is with the release mode and not debug.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any idea what might be causing this? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you resolved the problem?